# WARNING: BLAS library not found, Qiskit Installation

Tags: python, qiskit

I'm trying to install Qiskit and am coming across an error:

```
****************************************************************
*** WARNING: BLAS library not found.
* You can include the BLAS library in the global environment LDFLAGS, eg
*   export LDFLAGS='-L/path/to/blas/lib -lblas'
* or specify the BLAS library path in  PYSCF_INC_DIR
*   export PYSCF_INC_DIR=/path/to/blas/lib:/path/to/other/lib
****************************************************************
```

I'm on Mac OS El Capitan, and using Python 3.7.

If it helps, I ran `np.__config__` to see if I had BLAS installed, and it seemed to work since it returned this:

```py
openblas_lapack_info:
libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
language = c
define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

So I think this is just an issue with my Qiskit installation. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got same error and I'm with Sierra.

Assuming you already created and activated an environment with Anaconda, try to run

```sh
conda install -c pyscf pyscf
```

and then again:

```sh
pip install qiskit
```

I got the solution from [PySCF's docs](https://sunqm.github.io/pyscf/install.html).